# Multiples Conditions Sum SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, conditional-statements

I am aiming to produce code that generates an independent total check. As per the below table:

```
column1   Column2   Column3   value   independent total check
A         B         C         10      Null                   
A         B         E         11      Null                   
A         B         total     21      21                    
x         y         z         10      Null                   
x         y         p         20      Null                   
x         y         total     30      30
```

I am trying to employ a conditional sum, but with no success! What I have at the moment is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #Temp
select  t2.Column1, t2.Column2, t2.Column3,t2.value, independanttotal = 
case 
when t2.Column1 ='A' and t2.Column2= 'B'and t2.T_subdesk = 'Total' then sum(t2.value) 
when t2.Column1 ='x' and t2.Column2= 'y'and t2.T_subdesk = 'Total' then sum(t2.value) 
end
into #Temp 
from #Temp_A t2
group by t2.Column1,t2.Column2,t2.Column3,t2.value
```

but this is clearly incorrect, although it produces the correct result actually I am just reproducing the total value. Do I need some kind of nested sum? Do I need to separate out this into different table? this is really frustrating me
thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You have no `sum()` in your "conditional sum".

Comment: indeed, but if I put sum in we end up with many columns for the independent total as you need sum(...) as x independent value. So if I have many values in column1and Column2 then the independent total values end up with load of columns. How can I make it just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when column3 <> 'total' then value end) over (partition by column1, column2) as independent_total
from #temp t;
```

This puts the computation on all rows.  I don't think that is a problem, but you can use a `case` expression outside the `sum()` if that is really an issue.

If you only want this on the "total" row, you can do:

```
select t.*,
       (case when column3 = 'total'
             then sum(case when column3 <> 'total' then value end) over (partition by column1, column2)
        end) as independent_total
from #temp t;
```

Or, you slightly simplify the logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when column3 = 'total'
             then sum(value) over (partition by column1, column2) - value
        end) as independent_total
from #temp t;
```

This gets the total sum for the two columns and then subtracts the value on the `'total'` row.

Comment: cool, but how doe I label the column independent total? sorry am pretty new to SQL

Comment: Also, what is an outer case expression? sorry

Comment: @MrNemo, notice the second sql example... it has two case statements... the outer is based on when = 'total', the THEN portion does the <> 'total'

Comment: You can also label columns using `label =` before the formula instead of `as label` after. Can be easier to read when the formula is long or spans multiple lines.